Background colour of a wxControl-based custom control
I have a simple custom control consisting of wxStaticText and wxTextCtrl in one sizer.
#include "wx/control.h"

class CParamCtrlEx : public wxControl
{
public:
    CParamCtrlEx(void);
    CParamCtrlEx(wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY, float value_act = 0.0, float value_sp = 0.0, int dec_places = 1);
    ~CParamCtrlEx() {};

    bool Create(wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id);

private:
    wxBoxSizer *sizer_ = nullptr;
    wxStaticText *act_ = nullptr;
    wxTextCtrl *sp_ = nullptr;

    float value_act_ = 0.0;
    float value_sp_ = 0.0;
    int dec_places_ = 1;

private:
    void UpdateDisplay();

CParamCtrlEx::CParamCtrlEx(void)
{
}

CParamCtrlEx::CParamCtrlEx(wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id, float value_act, float value_sp, int dec_places) :
    value_act_(value_act),
    value_sp_(value_sp),
    dec_places_(dec_places)
{
    this->Create(parent, id);
}

bool CParamCtrlEx::Create(wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id)
{
    if (!this->wxControl::Create(parent, id, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBORDER_NONE))
        return false;

    wxControl::InheritAttributes();

    act_ = new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, wxString::Format("%.*f /", dec_places_, value_act_));
    sp_ = new wxTextCtrl(this, wxID_ANY, wxString::Format("%.*f", dec_places_, value_sp_), wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(50, -1), wxTE_RIGHT);

    sizer_ = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    sizer_->Add(act_, wxSizerFlags(0).Align(wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL).Border(wxRIGHT, 5));
    sizer_->Add(sp_, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand().Border(wxLEFT | wxRIGHT, 0).FixedMinSize());

    this->SetSizer(sizer_);
    this->Layout();

    return true;
}

void CParamCtrlEx::UpdateDisplay()
{
    act_->SetLabel(wxString::Format("%.*f /", dec_places_, value_act_));
    sp_->SetValue(wxString::Format("%.*f", dec_places_, value_sp_));
    Refresh();
}

Everything would be fine, if it weren't for the fact that my control has for some reason a different background colour than its parent wxPanel. It is somewhat darker.
I tried to use wxTRANSPARENT_WINDOW style when calling this->wxControl::Create(...), but without success.
How do I fix the background colour?

It turned out that the problem is that my control is placed on a panel which is a page in wxNotebook. The panel background in notebook is automatically set to a different colour than the background colour of panel placed in wxFrame. My control was adopting the colour of the latter.
Overriding the HasTransparentBackground() function to return true as is done in wxStaticText for example, solved the problem.
